# Descartar valores de entrada en Python

Tags: python

Cómo puedo hacer que si el input de alguien no está en mi lista de inputs posibles, haya un bucle y se lo pida otra vez?

```
operacion=input("Introduce la operación a realizar (suma, resta, multiplica, divide): ")

operaciones=(suma, resta, multiplica, divide)

if operacion=="suma":
    print(suma(op1,op2))
    
elif operacion=="resta":
    print(resta(op1,op2))
    
elif operacion=="multiplica":
    print(multiplica(op1,op2))
    
elif operacion=="divide":
    print(divide(op1,op2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso se hace un booleano inicializado en `False` para que entre en el bucle `while` y una lista de opciones posibles. Si el input concuerda con una de las opciones posibles, el booleano pasa a True y se cierra el bucle `while` del `input()`.

```
operaciones=("suma", "resta", "multiplica", "divide")
ok = False
while not ok:
    operacion=input("Introduce la operación a realizar (suma, resta, multiplica, divide): ")
    if operacion.lower() in operaciones:
        ok = True
if operacion=="suma":
    print(suma(op1,op2))

elif operacion=="resta":
    print(resta(op1,op2))

elif operacion=="multiplica":
    print(multiplica(op1,op2))

elif operacion=="divide":
    print(divide(op1,op2))
```

Comment: Que es esto? ...

Comment: Bueno, no se si lo he entendido mal, pero entiendo que pide un input en bucle hasta que el usuario escriba una opción de las disponibles. En este caso se hace un booleano inicializado en False para que entre en el bucle while y una lista de opciones posibles. Si el input concuerda con una de las opciones posibles, el booleano pasa a True y se cierra el bucle while del input.

Comment: Exactamente!!. Una respuesta debe ir con una descripción de como es que solucionas el problema, recuerda que la respuesta es para todos y no solo para ti o para el autor de la pregunta, **todos** leerán esta respuesta y sin una explicación, servirá de poco.

Comment: Disculpa, es la primera respuesta que publico y al poner el formato en código no he sabido poner el comentario. Ahora edito la respuesta con la explicación.

Comment: No te preocupes, haz el [tour] para que sepas como funciona el sitio. Y bienvenido a StackOverflow y gracias por contribuir.

Comment: gracias!! esto era exactamente lo que buscaba. la otra respuesta también funcionaba, pero llevo poquísimo programando y no la entendía (y no quería copiar y pegar sin entenderlo).

Comment: @MateoReyEdreira era que me digas que no entendías y así explicaba cada concepto :/, bueno no importa, ninguna respuesta es incorrecta solo hay unas más simplificadas y esto es algo fundamental en python que entenderás cuando sepas más :D.

Comment: @kinetick8 por cierto puedes ahorrarte la variable `ok`

Comment: sí, tienes razón... aún así, muchas gracias!! :)

Answer (score 4):

Creo que la forma más sencilla y simplificada de hacerlo es declarar un diccionario que contenga como claves las operaciones a realizar y como valor una simple función lambda, de esta forma solo comprobamos que lo ingresado exista en el diccionario y ejecutamos la función.

```py
operaciones = {"suma":lambda x,y: x+y, "resta": lambda x,y: x-y}
while True:
    operacion = input("ingrese una operacion: ").lower()
    if operacion in operaciones.keys():
        resultado = operaciones[operacion](op1,op2)
        print(resultado)
        break
```

Haces lo mismo con las demás operaciones de multiplicar y dividir.